# PhoneGap on windows 8.1 64 bit error with Platform add android command

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, windows-8.1

I have been trying to setup Android, Phonegap,and eclipse. I installed the 64 bit versions successfully. I am using the latest version of Node.JS V0.10.21 I am trying to setup my first project. I get an error executing this line.

> cordova platform add android

The error is below

> [command failed to execute: ant jar]

The debug is as follows

> Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. Creating Cordova
>   project for the Android platform:
>
> at C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\platform.js:246:30
>      at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
>      at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>      at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
>      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)

Comment: If you add on `--verbose` to the end of the command what is the output you get then? My guess is that the SDK isn't completely installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you [installed the Android SDK](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide_install_the_sdk) and is it available in your `PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) has not been installed yet, or its PATH was not defined.